Could the Relativity of Time Impact the P vs NP Problem?
Given that time behaves differently under relativistic conditions (such as near black holes or in high-speed motion), could the relative nature of time influence the complexity classes P and NP? For example, if time were dilated or accelerated, could NP-hard problems become solvable in polynomial time depending on the observer’s frame of reference?

P vs. NP isn't really about "time" though, is it?  We say "polynomial time" but we really mean "polynomial complexity."

P and NP are about the number of steps that some algorithm takes to solve some problems. How much time each step takes is not a consideration.

No. The P vs. NP question is a purely formal question. The definitions of P and NP do not depend on time and physics, they are based on an idealized model of computation, Turing machines, where we count time complexity by the number of atomic steps the machine takes to complete the computation.
Of course, the twin paradox implies that you could theoretically embark on a space ship, fly at near light speed and come back on Earth after a very long computation completed while feeling only a few hours have passed. But this has no bearing on $\text{P} \overset{?}{=} \text{NP}$.
